# Add paging to existing ActionResult controller that passes ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, paging, model-view

I’m using an MVC 5, EF 6, Code First Web Application in Visual Studio 2013 Pro from here:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I would like to combine a view that has paging functionality and that also has the ability to display related data from a ViewModel.

In the referenced web application above, the Student Index view (ViewResult in Controller) has the paging and sorting functionality and does not use a ViewModel.

In the same application, the Instructor Index view (ActionResult in Controller) does not have the paging and sorting functionality, but it does display related data(Courses) through the use of a “Select” Html.ActionLink on the same page as the Instructor Index data.

I like the Student view that provides the paging and sorting functionality and I also like the Instructor view that provides the ability to display related data on the existing Index page, but I don’t know how to combine them.

Does anybody know how I can add the paging functionality to the Instructor Index view while still keeping the ability to display the related data on the same Index view page?

Another way to ask the same question would be: How to add paging and sorting to the Instructor Index view while still keeping the ability to display the related data?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks,
Tony

Here is the Index method from the InstructorController.cs:

```
        public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var instructors = from i in db.Instructors
                       select i;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            instructors = instructors.Where(i => i.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || i.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                instructors = instructors.OrderByDescending(i => i.LastName);
                break;
            case "Date":
                instructors = instructors.OrderBy(i => i.HireDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                instructors = instructors.OrderByDescending(i => i.HireDate);
                break;
            default:  // Name ascending 
                instructors = instructors.OrderBy(i => i.LastName);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(instructors.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

Here is the beginning of the view code for Instructor/Index.cshtml:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<LakesidePurchasing.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Instructors";
    }

    <h2>Instructors</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Hire Date</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Courses</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            string selectedRow = "";
            if (item.ID == ViewBag.InstructorID)
            {
                selectedRow = "success";
            }
            <tr class="@selectedRow">
                <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HireDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (item.OfficeAssignment != null)
            {
                @item.OfficeAssignment.Location
            }
        </td>
```

Comment: To summarise - you want a View displaying Instructor information together with a paged list of child records?

Comment: I just want to add the paging and sorting ability to the Instructor Index view and keep everything else the same.  I do not want a paged list for the child records.

Comment: I don't understand - what is the data that should be paged? Courses?

Comment: I wish that I could show you a picture of it, but if you run the application from that tutorial and click on the "Instructor" menu option, It will show a list of Instructors(Index view).  That is what I want paged.  Thanks.

Comment: I think I've seen it on the pdf. Is it a list of instructors with a list of courses and a list of students?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: so it would be easy to page the instructor results use the [PagedList library](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList), but I'm not sure how you would deal with the 'Courses' and 'Students' data

Comment: Yes, I have added paging to the Instructor view and it works fine.  I just need to know how to retain the ability to display the related data(Courses and Students).  I believe it is in the return from the controller.  I have "return View(instructors.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));", but I need to know how to include the related data in that return.

Comment: You need to return a model that _contains_ the pagedlist data AND the Students AND the courses.  You must have dome something similar already as the demo has those 3 datasets displayed on the page

Comment: I agree with the first sentence in your comment.  I'm a bit puzzled by your next statement.  I lose the ability to display the related datasets(Courses and Students) because the model passed does not include them.  You make it sound like I created this tutorial program.

Comment: Sorry - I just meant that if you followed the tutorial, surely you must have passed a model containing the 3 datasets? I only skimmed the pdf so apologies if I made a glaring misjudgement. Anyway, it boils down to the fact that you need to include the 'courses' and 'students' in a model which you pass to the view.  I understand that the paged data only contains Instructor data, so you need to get the other data somehow, realistically in a 2nd query.

Comment: Yes, I can see in the application that the Instructor ViewModel has "InstructorIndexData.cs" which contains an IEnumerable for Instructor, Course and Enrollment.  After changing the Instructor Index view to use the PagedList library, it is not using the ViewModel, consequently losing the related data.

Comment: You should still use the `InstructorIndexData` model, but instead of the property `IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors`, you use `PagedList.IPagedList<Instructor> Instructors` and assign your `instructors.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize) to it`

Comment: Reading code in the comments is awful, sorry about that - I tried to move it to chat but with only 1 reputation point, it wasn't allowed!

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I will try that and let you know.  Have a Happy Thanksgiving.  Tony

Comment: That did not work.  The Index view could find the fields to display (@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)).  Thanks.

Comment: could or could _not_?

Comment: Sorry Mark.  Could NOT.  Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're now using the `InstructorIndexData` model, you'll need to modify the view controls so they access the `Instructor` properties. Something like: `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Instructors.LastName)`

Comment: I cannot get this to work.  The intellisense does not bring up the field names or the model name instructor.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your original question & add the code that populates the model (from the controller)?

Comment: You're not using the `InstructorIndexData` model.

Comment: The original Index method for InstructorController used the InstructorIndexData model.  That's why I am here, because I would like someone to help combine the original Instructor Index method which uses the InstructorIndexData model with the new Instructor Index method which uses paging.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was your original model:

```
public class InstructorIndexData
{
  public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

You want to show paged Instructor data so you need to change it to this:

```
public class InstructorIndexData
   {
      public PagedList.IPagedList<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
   }
```

Populated like this:

```
var model = new InstructorIndexData
{
    Instructors = instructors.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize),
    Courses = ?,
    Enrollments = ?
}
return View(model);
```

The model that you pass to the view hasn't changed, but the way you access the Instructor records has, although I gather you can successfully display the paged data.
How the Courses & Enrollments properties are populated depends on what data should be shown, you should be able to set them to null initially just to get it working(you will probably have to have checks for null in the View to avoid an error if it tries to display a value from a null property)

**UPDATE**:

change the View @model declaration:

```
@model InstructorIndexData
```

and in the foreach...

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Instructors)
        {
           <td>@item.LastName</td>
           ... etc
```

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid expression term '?'" on the question marks(?).  Thanks.

Comment: That's meant to indicate 'i don't know what you want here'

Comment: OK.  I used "null" for Courses and Enrollments.  The view already contained checks for Courses and Enrollments being null.  I still cannot get the view to find the fields to DisplayFor.  Thanks.

Comment: Please add an example of the View code where this is the case

Comment: Try using `StaticPagedList` as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList#example-2-manual-paging)